# Generate declaration file with single module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, npm, type-declaration

Given the following folder structure:

```
src/
├── foo.ts
├── bar.ts
├── baz.ts
├── index.ts
```

Where `foo.ts`, `bar.ts`, and `baz.ts` each export a default class or thing: i.e. in the case of `foo.ts`:

```
export default class Foo {
    x = 2;
}
```

Can we **automatically generate** a declaration file which declares **one module** `my-module` and exports `foo.ts`, `bar.ts`, and `baz.ts` as **non-defaults**?

I.e. I want `tsc` to generate the following:

```
build/
├── foo.js
├── bar.js
├── baz.js
├── index.js
├── index.d.ts
```

Where `index.d.ts` contains:

```
declare module 'my-module' {
    export class Foo {
        ...
    }
    export class Bar {
        ...
    }
    export class Baz {
        ...
    }
}
```

I see that mostly all NPM modules have a declaration file like this and maybe with separate files.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: [This TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4433) is for generating a "flattened" declaration file and has links to some third-party tools that you could try.  May I ask why you want this?  Generating a `.d.ts` file per `.js` file will work fine for being able to find type information, though a flattened `.d.ts` file may be easier for users to understand and may make it easier to hide elements that you don't consider public API.

Answer (score 0):

In your tsconfig.json file, set "declaration" to true. Then when you run typescript on your project it will automatically generate declaration files for you.

Comment: Johan is asking how to bundle all type declaration files in one instead of emitting the type declaration file.

Answer (score 0):

##### [tsup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsup)

It can do that and is pretty fast (1.5s):

```
tsup ./executors/index.ts --dts-only
```

You need to import the types in `./executors/index.ts` and export them from this file.

##### [dts-bundle-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dts-bundle-generator)

It was slower for me (8.5s):

```
dts-bundle-generator --out-file dist/testkube-executors.d.ts ./executors/executors.ts
```